# How to get value of an attribute with namespace

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I'd like to get the content of the attribute **xsi:schemaLocation**. It's works perfectly with getElementsByTagName in php (and foreach after) but it's ugly, right ?

How to get the same content with a simple Xpath query ?

Here a short example of the xml content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gpx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" creator="blabla" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd http://www.groundspeak.com/cache/1/0/1 http://www.groundspeak.com/cache/1/0/1/cache.xsd" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0">
...
</gpx>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why is it ugly? xpath probably does the same thing internally, searching for elements in a loop that has the attribute etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [SimpleXMLElement class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) you can easily get the attribute **xsi:schemaLocation**'s value:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gpx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" creator="blabla" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd http://www.groundspeak.com/cache/1/0/1 http://www.groundspeak.com/cache/1/0/1/cache.xsd" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0">
</gpx>
XML;

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$schemaLocation = $sxe->attributes('xsi', true)->schemaLocation;

echo (string) $schemaLocation;
```

Comment: Just bear in mind that this will only work if the document is guaranteed to use xsi as the namespace prefix for XMLSchema-instance attributes. It's typically not a good idea to rely on that.

Answer (score 3):

Typically you need to register the namespaces you want to use with the XPath library first. Then you can query the attribute by including namespace prefix along with the name.

So let's assume you're using DOMXPath, you might register the following namespaces:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace("xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
$xpath->registerNamespace("gpx", "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0");
```

And then you can query the schemaLocation attribute with something like this:

```
$xpath->query("/gpx:gpx/@xsi:schemaLocation",$doc);
```

Comment: If you've chosen to go with the solution provided by Rolando, just be aware of the risks I mentioned in the comments.