# php SimpleXML get full namespace attributes

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, simplexml

I cannot understand why I'm not able to extract all namespaces attributes from an XML like this:

```
<MapData
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:semi-org:xsd.E142-1.V0211.SubstrateMap"
    xmlns:sme="urn:st-com:xsd.E142-1.V0211.SubstrateMap-STmicroelectronics-V1015"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:semi-org:xsd.E142-1.V0211.SubstrateMap E142-1-V0211.SubstrateMap-ST-V1015.xsd"
 >
 (...)
 </MapData>
```

Then with

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement();
$xml->getNamespaces();
```

I obtain

```
Array
(
    [xsi] => http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
    [] => urn:semi-org:xsd.E142-1.V0211.SubstrateMap
    [sme] => urn:st-com:xsd.E142-1.V0211.SubstrateMap-STmicroelectronics-V1015
)
```

but why value of `xsi:schemaLocation` is not returned as well?

Comment: Bcoz its not a namespace. Find your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407930/how-to-get-value-of-an-attribute-with-namespace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get value of an attribute with namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16408053/1255289)